# Display selected results from MYSQL generated dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql, forms, drop-down-menu

Any one know of a code that will display the results from a dropdown list which has been populated from a mysql database? need it for the site http://www.holidayaviemore.com for the dropdown lists at the top of the page. Thanks

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

On your script

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: test.php,
   cache: false,
   success: function(html){
    $('select').append(html);
   }
});
```

test.php

```
foreach($result as $row){

 echo '<option value="'.$row->key.'">'.$row->value.'</option>';

}
```